# What cut of beef can I use to make "sukiyaki beef"?

Tags: meat, beef, japanese-cuisine, butchering

I want to try a recipe for Gyudon (shown below) that calls for thin-sliced "Sukiyaki Beef". My local grocery store doesn't carry anything by that name. I'm comfortable with thin-slicing beef myself (possibly partially freezing it first), but I'm unsure what cut to start with.

What types or cuts of beef should I start with for Sukiyaki, Gyudon, Shabu Shabu, or other "Sukiyaki Beef" dishes?

I happen to have a rump roast in my freezer. Will that work?

[image: Recipe for Gyudon]

Conclusion: Made it with rump roast. It sliced easily, cooked perfectly, and was tender and delicious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best choices would be top sirloin (#1 choice), tenderloin, or one of the other (less expensive) sirloin cuts. Those cuts will be tender, flavorful, and without pockets of fat or gristle to mar the appearance of your dish.

I don't recommend round because I simply don't like its flavor. Using round in this application might be one of the best applications to use up round, but for the best possible beef bowl, I'd go with the sirloin or tenderloin.

TIP: To thinly slice meat, put it in the freezer first until it just starts to get hard (not even close to fully frozen), or start with meat that is only partially defrosted. Partially frozen meat is *much* easier to neatly and thinly slice. For this application, thin even slices really are important, they make for a much nicer presentation.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend tenderloin -- it doesn't have enough fat.  You'd want something well marbled.

Comment: @Joe To me tenderloin is a distant second to sirloin, but really OK. You definitely don't want anything with more fat than sirloin.